# CLI arguments in `new-bench` command in `cabal`

Tags: haskell, benchmarking, cabal, cabal-new

I'm trying to pass the `--small` option from [`hs-gauge`](https://github.com/vincenthz/hs-gauge#features-compared-to-criterion) benchmarking library.

I am looking to something similar to what is in `stack` so I could simply write:

```
cabal new-bench --benchmark-arguments="--small"
```

How can I pass the argument to the `cabal new-bench` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, this usage is not supported by `new-bench`:  https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4643 (a workaround is to run the executable(s) manually)